# Git naming convention for successor branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control, naming-conventions, conventions

Imagine there is a feature branch (let's call it `lunch`) branched from `master`. I branch a new branch `lunch-pancakes` from `feature`. After committing some code to `lunch-pancakes`, while someone else commits to `lunch` we decide to merge the changes. I rebase `lunch-pancakes` on `lunch`, merge it and then delete the branch.

Now, the development of pancakes hasn't stopped, and I want to do further changes into the code involving them, so I branch `lunch` into a new subfeature branch. How should I name it?

- `lunch-pancakes` seems like a really bad idea
- `lunch-pancakes-update` won't work for long. What do I do, when the situation arises again?
- `lunch-pancakes2` might be acceptable?

I don't want to name it after a specific sub-sub-feature (`lunch-pancakes-toppings`) as I don't know which subsubfeatures, bugfixes and other changes concerning `lunch-pancakes` are going to be committed to this branch before we decide to merge it into `lunch` again.

Or is the workflow just plain wrong? How do you handle branch naming in such circumstances?

Comment: Why did you delete the old `lunch-pancakes` branch in the first place? Why do you think naming it `lunch-pancakes` would be a bad idea?

Comment: I delete the old branch when I want to branch from `lunch` with a fresh branch again. However, I feel like reusing branch names could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have long gone away from naming branches like this. The branches given by my particular workflow are named `master`, `qa` and whatever, and always stay that way. The namespace of all other branches is "flat" and equal to their name in my issue tracking system (Jira format, e.g. `PROJ-12345`, where `PROJ` is the short project name from Jira). This makes it easy to crossreference (automatically and manually).

As a side point, I *never* re-use a branch name (i.e. a Jira issue) after that feature branch has merged back into the production code. Think of a feature more as a "development event", not so much as a feature in your application.

Aside from that, there is no official naming convention; `git` is agnostic of the workflow.